# Mailchimp/Civicrm synchronization

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I just recently upgraded to Civicrm 5.9.1. I had used the Mailchimp extension in the past in test mode previous to our current Civicrm upgrades, and now want to implement it. I was behaving weirdly after the upgrade, so I uninstalled it and then reinstalled it.

I have the newest 2.0.1 version installed, the permissions should be correct since I've assigned all user roles to the Mailchimp: allow webhook posts, and I've verified the webhook is running (doing a Mailings -> Mailchimp settings -> Save and Test responds that the API is returning the correct information from Mailchimp). We're still running Wordpress 4.9.9.

When I attempt a manual sync in one of the Mailchimp sync choices under Mailings, I get a description screen, but no ability to do anything. Has anyone else seen this behaviour or have insights?

There's nothing in error logs that indicate anything is happening with PHP. We're running PHP 7.1.26.

[image]

Comment: any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Only thing in the console is:
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 75ms

Comment: Can you please see if you can replicate this issue on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: I'm getting back to this if possible - gave up in January and moved onto other things. Hassan, the link you provided is not for Wordpress, so I used the Wordpress demo site instead. I got the same results there. It looks like this plugin is definitely broken with the newer versions of Wordpress. That's too bad, because now I've got to do manual updates whenever anyone adds a new contact that needs to also be in Mailchimp.

Comment: This is in the error log: PHP Warning: Declaration of CRM Mailchimp Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in /home/sxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/CRM/Mailchimp/Permission.php on line 40

BTW, I've checked all roles for permissions, not only anonymous, but still no correct display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the change suggested here to get rid of the php problems and then reset everything and that seems to have solved the problem. Not sure what was happening, but at least things are working now. [mailchimp extension error, php 7.1, civi 5.10.4, drupal 7.x](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28956/mailchimp-extension-error-php-7-1-civi-5-10-4-drupal-7-x)